# How to change the "/blog" of the url in a RefineryCMS app if you set the blog as the root and want to just display the domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, refinerycms

I set the blog as the root already. Then followed the tutorial at http://refinerycms.com/guides/page-titles-and-urls which says that to change the default slugs from Refinery, I needed to modify `config/initializers/refinery/pages.rb` to have `config.use_custom_slugs = true` . That part is done.

My blog is going to go on a subdomain similar to `blog.example.com` so hence it looks bad if I have `blog.example.com/blog`

So I already made sure to redirect the "home" to `www.example.com` so now I need to know how to remove the `/blog` from the url. So that click on "Blog" takes you to `blog.example.com`

In the Advanced Options, I tried setting the custom slug to "/" but that did not work as intended.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your routes.rb file to redirect to the blog index page. Make sure you put it before mounting the Refinery Core Engine.

```
Yourapp::Application.routes.draw do

root :to => 'refinery/blog/posts#index'

# This line mounts Refinery's routes at the root of your application.
# This means, any requests to the root URL of your application will go to Refinery::PagesController#home.
# If you would like to change where this extension is mounted, simply change the :at option to something different.
#
# We ask that you don't use the :as option here, as Refinery relies on it being the default of "refinery"
mount Refinery::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The Refinery Blog engine initializer has a "page_url" option you can change.

Uncomment the following line in config/initializers/refinery/blog.rb :

```
# config.page_url = "/blog"
```

And change it to

```
config.page_url = "/"
```

Not sure if this will work with a custom subdomain, but this is how to replace the default '/blog' route

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with the innards of Refinery, but try putting this at the top of your routes.rb file:

```
get '/', to: redirect('/blog')
```

That should allow you to use the domain you want, though I believe it will redirect to the `/blog` before rendering.

Comment: Oh I seem to have presented the intent incorrectly. The root already forwards to `/blog` but I wanted the url in the address bar to just display the domain without the page. So just `blog.example.com` as opposed to `blog.example.com/blog`

Comment: Got it. The answer here would allow you to link to it as `blog.example.com`, and then it would redirect to `blog.example.com/blog`, which the user probably wouldn't notice.  Not sure how you achieve what you want with Refinery; it would be very straightforward if you knew what controller you were routing to within Refinery, but I don't know that.